# Split String and add \n after 23 characters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have long address as a string I want to add new line after 23 characters because in printing of a4 page the string it cuts down. So I want to create them in new line.

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? You can't just tell us what you want and wait for us to do it for you. You need to determine the logic first and then write code to implement that logic. If the code doesn't work as expected, then you've got a question ask, which requires showing us what you've and explaining what happens.

Comment: Sorry I was trying with for loop and sub string but not able to get what I wanted to thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to show us that then. A question on SO requires a full explanation of the problem, including what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all your time here is how I solved it

```
 If delivery_address.TextLength > 23 Then
        delivery_address.Text = delivery_address.Text.Insert(23, Environment.NewLine)
    End If
```